# Long commands split over multiple lines in Windows with quotes

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

Using the caret to split lines,

```
dir ^
*.bat ^
/w
```

works as expected, but

```
dir ^
"*.bat" ^
```

won't let me enter the "/w". I guess the caret does not work after a double quote. Is this a bug? Or if this is a feature, what is it's use and how can I get around it?

Answer (score 6):

I found the answer myself:

```
dir ^
 ^"*.bat^" ^ 
 /w
```

works as I want. In the second line there must be spaces before the first caret and after the last. (using Vista SP2)

Answer (score 4):

An alternative solution that has worked for me (Windows Server 2012) is to include a tab on the subsequent line. For example:

```
dir ^
    "*.bat" ^
    /w
```

In my experience a tab character can replace a space when delimiting arguments to a command or script. I also feel that this has a cleaner look.

However, I haven't spent time testing it under every possible batch-file syntax scenario and it's possible there are some where it won't apply or work properly.

Comment: EDIT: specified Windows version where I've used this